# why am i getting an object invalid error?

Tags: python, maya

I think there is something wrong with my naming convention but I'm not sure how to fix it. it keeps giving me an invalid object even when tried to name it based on the vertex please help.

```
for i in range(1,100):
    print i

def cactus():
#creating base of cactus
    cmds.polyCylinder(sc=1,sa=10,sh=10, n= "cactus1_Base["+str(i)+"]")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
# Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 17: Object cactus1_Base[99].e[140:169] is invalid this is the error im getting and the code is
```

Comment: @Kayla, you should provide the piece code you are working with. If you don't understand your code, you should begin with python basics : string operation, loops, list, definition, return statement, these fundamentals are enough to do everything you need in maya. When you are familiar with python basics you should be able to jump into maya 'python based on mel', maya python doc is really good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have maya this week so I cant really check the result of this code
The first piece of codes woulld be for me the best solution but you have also the second one.

Note that in your code, character '[' and ']' are reserved in maya for components : vtx[], e[], f[]...etc
so you cant use them for naming

Secondly when you create your iteration 'i', it is outside your function so there is no real connection between i and your function cactus()
So you have to think on how you want to create cactus. That why I have written those two examples :
the first consider that you are creating cactus elements
the second one is just for creating a bunch of cactus

You could go beyond with kwargs and try to mimic cmds.polyCylinder

Just in case a bit python lessons for maya : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDKxDbt6EGQ&t=4s

```
def nameChecker(name, start=0, max=100000, stringFormat=True):   
    if not '{' in name:
        stringFormat = False
    a = start
    while a < max:
        if stringFormat:
            confName = name.format(a)
        else:
            confName = name + str(a)
        if not cmds.objExists(confName):
            return confName
        a+=1

def create_cactus(baseName='cactus1_Base_{:03d}'):
    name_conform = nameChecker(baseName)
    cactus = cmds.polyCylinder(sc=1,sa=10,sh=10, n=name_conform)[0]
    return cactus

cactus_output = []
for i in range(1,100):
    cactus = create_cactus()
    cactus_output.append(cactus)
print(cactus_output )
```

OR more simple :

```
def create_cactus(nb_of_cactus=100):
    cactus_output = []
    for nb in range(nb_of_cactus):
        name = "cactus1_Base_{}".format(nb)
        cactus = cmds.polyCylinder(sc=1,sa=10,sh=10, n=name)[0]
        cactus_output.append(cactus)
    return cactus
myCactus= create_cactus(100)
print(myCactus)
```

or based on selection :

```
def create_cactusVtx():
    mysel = cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
    for i in range(len(mysel)):
        id = mysel.split('[')[-1][:-1]
        name = "cactus1_Base_{}".format(i)
        cactus = cmds.polyCylinder(sc=1,sa=10,sh=10, n=name)[0]
```

Comment: sadly what i need and it is too specific to sift through hours of videos which I have done for weeks and none of it truly helps me. my homework is to create this cactus and move it to selected points while randomizing the rotation and size i thank you for your help with the naming convention but its still doesn't work if you can help me out with adding randomize function to this code it would be really appreciated. `for ver in list:
    vertPos= cmds.xform(ver,q=True,ws =True,t= True)
    obj= cactus()
    cmds.move(vertPos[0],vertPos[1],vertPos[2],obj, a= True, r= True)
    `

Comment: Type "python random module" and then use cmds.setAttr. thr video ive linked is pretty mich creating sphere and moving them. 1 hour of video doesnt seems to be really a big deal.... Go on creativecrash, download a randomizer script and look at the code for studying.